# display vertical tabs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to use vertical tabs,
I have implemented vertical tab shown in documentation.It is working fine.
I want to display tabs in vertical direction like dhtmlx vertical tabs.
[like this](http://mehdi.biz/blog/2010/02/05/vertical-tabs-for-jquery-lovers/)
I want to display tabs in the right side and display content in the left side.can u tell me how to do this?

Comment: You should be able to do it with positioning instructions in the CSS. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i changed the position of the menu to right using `float: right`

Updated changes below in the provided `CSS` will work fine

```
#vtab > ul {
    float: right;
}

#vtab > div {
    margin-right: 110px;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsTAU/)

I suggest you to see the below links which will be useful on layouts

[Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

[How to Use CSS Positioning to Create Layouts Without Tables](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa102102a.htm)

Comment: Thanks,it is working fine.Tab name is not displaying,can u tell me why it is displaying?

Comment: @user1990132, They have used images in code which is not added in fiddle. Try the changes with your implementation and it will work

Comment: I want to change the look of tabs,I want curvey edges to the tabs,Is it possible?

Comment: @user1990132 yes it is possible. apply `li` this property `-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px`

Comment: @user1990132 also you need to add `-moz-border-radius` -ms-border-radius` `-op-border-radius` to work with every browser, the above one will only work on `chrome`